# Humble Bundle's Beat the average

Tags: humble-bundle

Does anybody know about the two locks on a single bundle? I am talking about the green lock price and the blue lock price. For eg, in the last Humble Weekly Sega sale, the Total War Shogun 2 was only given to those who donate more than $16. Will that game still be available to obtain after the bundle period by boosting the amount? I have already beat the average of $6 and got 11 games. But I really wanted Shogun 2.

EDIT:

This is the response I got from Humble Bundle Customer support. I think they should know more about the Humble Bundle

```
 Martin 
 MAR 31, 2014  |  02:17PM PDT 
 So does this mean that even if I add $10 to Increase The Amount, and reach $16, I won't get Shogun 2. Also, I would like to know if this is the same for all items shown with a Blue Padlock icon.

Rylee 
MAR 31, 2014  |  05:52PM PDT

Hi Martin,
This is correct. Once the bundle is over the offer has then since expired. This includes any order adders.
Any game in a bundle with a padlock beside the title will be marked as either a Beat the Average, Beat the $6 or $15. As long as purchases made at or exceeding these levels, or have had enough added to the existing order during the designated Bundle sale time will receive any games that are “locked”.
Thank you!
Rylee 
Support Ninja
Humble Bundle
```

Comment: As far as I know, after the bundle sale is over you can't obtain any BTA games by boosting your donation amount.

Comment: Once the sale is over...the sale is over...plain and simple

Comment: Actually, if we have paid an amount for the bundle, we can boost the amount and get BTA games within 30 days after the sale is over. This is true for those games which are shown with a green padlock. I want to know about the game shown with the blue padlock.

Comment: @thomarjos If you have an official source or have verified this with personal experience, feel free to answer your own question.  As for your question, [their support](http://support.humblebundle.com/customer/portal/articles/1384105-how-do-i-add-more-to-my-order-to-unlock-additional-games-) does not seem to differentiate between different locking tiers (i.e. blue vs. green).

Comment: @Batophobia I know it because I've done it. For the Weekly Sega Sale, I paid only $1 the first time. When the bundle was over, the option to increase the amount like shown in their support page, was their. It also stated how much I have to increase in order to get BTA games. And I paid $5 more to get it to $6 and got the BTA games after the sale period. I am confused that it doesn't show the same for Shogun 2. It doesn't say how much I have to pay to get Shogun2. That's why I am confused.

Comment: You used to be able to donate more to get the BTA games after the sale had ended, but I'm pretty sure they stopped allowing that a long time ago *(some time around HB 4, after they raised the minimum price to $1)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Did you read what I said above? I raised the amount and got the BTA games. What I want to know is the one with the Blue padlock icon. I got Medieval Total War and other BTA games after the sale was over. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Humble_Bundles

Comment: Based on your update, it would seem that increasing enough to beat the blue lock price will get you the game.  *As long as purchases made at or exceeding these levels, **or have had enough added to the existing order** during the designated Bundle sale time will receive any games that are “locked”.*  It could be that they only have the "Add X to unlock" for the green locks since those are common.  Blue locks are fairly new, IIRC.

Comment: @Batophobia Problem is no one can confirm it, yet.

Comment: You might try continuing to bug the customer service rep until you get a definitive answer.  If the question seems to get lost in email text, you can also try calling.  Eventually you will get escalated to someone that can answer your question definitively.

Comment: @Batophobia Their customer service doesn't even know about the 30 day period for bundle owners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just experimentd on this. Just like you I had inquired, and just like you i boosted the first BTA and didn't get any more prompts. i JUST boosted up to the 15 and did indeed receive my copy of Shogun 2. You're wlcome, have a nice day and HAPPY GAMING!

Comment: I should've manned up and spend that money. Also, I think I found the difference between the colors. Green locks, means varying price, whereas blue locks means fixed price. That's the only think I noticed.